# How to update FPS dynamically on window title of cv2 in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am using `python` `opencv` to do some video related work. I am also calculating the FPS and showing it on top left corner of the cv2 window. Now instead of showing it in top left corner, I want to show it on window title. Below is the code:

```
import cv2
import datetime
import imutils

def GetCoord(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print("X: {} | Y: {}".format(x, y))

winName = "My Project"
cv2.namedWindow(winName)
cv2.setMouseCallback(winName, GetCoord)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fps_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
fps = 0
total_frames = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=800)
    total_frames = total_frames + 1
    fps_end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_diff = fps_end_time - fps_start_time
    if time_diff.seconds == 0:
        fps = 0.0
    else:
        fps = (total_frames / time_diff.seconds)
    fps_text = "FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps)
    cv2.putText(frame, fps_text, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    cv2.imshow(winName, frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Instead of showing it on top left corner, I want to do something like the below:

```
cv2.imshow(winName + " FPS: {}".format(fps_text), frame)
```

But doing so, the application performs very strangely and keeps opening a new windows. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Cause of the Problem:**

Each window in opencv has a **unique name**. The window is created with this name either when you call `cv2.namedWindow`, or implicitly when you call `cv2.imshow` with a new name.
By using:

```
cv2.imshow(winName + " FPS: {}".format(fps_text), frame)
```

You actually create **new windows** each time the `fps_text` is different than the ones before.

**The Solution:**

Each opencv window also has a **title** property. By default the window title is the window unique name, but these are 2 different properties.

You can use [**`cv2.setWindowTitle`**](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga56f8849295fd10d0c319724ddb773d96) to modify the title:

```
fps_text = "{:.2f}".format(fps)
winTitle = winName + " FPS: {}".format(fps_text)
cv2.setWindowTitle(winName, winTitle)
```

**Note** that the window unique name does not change.